# Trouble creating foreign key in Oracle create table

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

I'm building some really simple tables in Oracle and I'm having trouble creating foreign keys.  The fac_ID in Equipment is the FK that references fac_ID in faculty, but it is creating an error.

I'm using Oracle 11g Express.  When I run "select * from equipment" it produces the error " ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty(
fac_ID        VARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
fac_Street    VARCHAR(70)    NOT NULL,
fac_City    VARCHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
fac_PROV    VARCHAR(2)    NOT NULL,
fac_Phone    VARCHAR(12)    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (fac_ID)
); 

CREATE TABLE Equipment(
equip_ID        VARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
fac_ID            VARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
equip_Name       VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
equip_Quantity    VARCHAR(3)    NOT NULL,
equip_Purchase_Date    DATE    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (equip_ID),
CONSTRAINT fac_ID FOREIGN KEY (fac_ID) REFERENCES Faculty(fac_ID) 
);
```

Comment: Your code works for me, what error are you getting? Which version of Oracle are you using? Try changing the name of the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to some other name, for example, `fac_id_fk`.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej I'm using Oracle 11g Express.  When I run "select * from equipment" it produces the error " ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

Comment: Was the table created successfully? If you run this query: `SELECT * FROM user_objects WHERE object_name = 'EQUIPMENT';` does it return anything? Do you try to run the select statement while being logged as the same user as the user you were logged in during the creation of the tables?

Comment: Yes I'm logged in as the same person.  But even then "select * from equipment" should still yield the entire equipment table

Comment: The error you mention has nothing to do with a FK.  Run DESC faculty and then DESC equipment.  What do you get?

Comment: It's possible that the table was created with a case sensitive name, e.g. `"Equipment"`. Try running `SELECT 1 FROM "Equipment";`.

Answer (score 0):

Me too got the following error

> Error starting at line : 56 in command - drop table SONICLIVE.Address
>   purge Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not
>   exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

And what i did was change put the table name inside double quotes **"Address"**

```
CREATE TABLE "Studio" (
  "ID" NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  "NAME" VARCHAR(20),
  "PHONE" VARCHAR(11),
  "ADDRESS_ID" NUMBER,
  "MANAGER_ID" NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT fk_ADDRESS FOREIGN KEY (ADDRESS_ID) REFERENCES "Address"(ID)
);
```

And it worked. I was using Oracle llg r2 XE for local testing